# Moving an old build from ant to maven, have subdirectory of old static JARs, don't know groupIds or artifactIds, how write <dependencies>

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have an old `ant`-based build I must move to be Maven-based for our new build system. This old build is based on many well known libraries (Apache commons, etc.) which pose no problem to Maven, but it uses also about a dozen JARs in a subdirectory that are less well known or not known at all (can't find any information on) that I must include statically.

I have chosen this approach for including these more static JARs that I cannot get from Maven the way one would normally get them:

```
<repository>
  <id>Pile of misfit JARs</id>  
  <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
</repository>
```

However, when it comes to creating `<dependency>` statements for these misfits, in the case of most of the JARs all I have is knowledge of the Java package paths in the code. I don't know how to discover what to use as `groupId` and `artifactId`. I have looked inside these JARs; some do have good information in manifests, but others do not or have only partial information.

(Incidentally, to use the `<repository>` construction above, I have to make use of `$ mvn install:install-file ...` and name `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` too in addition to what I put into `<dependency>` in order to make the local, in-project repository work.)

I'm very grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I will provide few outline.

1. Apart from well known jar files like Apache commons etc, you have to look into Manifest.mf file inside the unidentified jar files. You will find some name, company name etc.
2. Then go to mvnrepository.com and search for the name or company name which you found from the unidentified jar files.
3. If you get the actual artifact detail from mvnrepository.com, you can include group id, artifact id etc in maven dependency.

How ever all the above approach is time consuming.

There is another approach to get rid of. If you have latest version of **Artifactory**. Upload the unidentified jar files into Artifactory, it will either identify the details or it will generate the group id, artifact id version etc. If you want, you can provide your own artifact details also.
You can also refer to link.
http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to upload those jars to your Maven repo with some fake groupIds/artifactIds/versions using [Maven deploy plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html). In this case you will be 100% sure that your Maven build uses the very same jars as your Ant build. Though you will still need to try to find our actual versions if you need to upgrade to newer version.

Comment: You're basically saying that I can do `$ mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -Dfile=path-to-jar -DgroupId=A -DartifactId=B -Dversion=C -Durl=Nexus-URL` with A, B and C as anything, put these into my intermediate repository, then consume them (using A, B, C)?

Comment: Yes, exactly this